# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед тире в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед тире?

*Всё, что ему было нужно, — любовь.*

Answer (score 3):

*Всё, что ему было нужно, **— любовь**.*

В предложении **такой структуры** тире ставится, так как пауза там присутствует в обязательном порядке. Также надо обратить внимание на то, чтобы это предложение хорошо вписывалось в контекст.

Другие варианты записи: *Всё, что ему было нужно, — **это любовь**.*

Также (без тире): *Всё, что ему нужно, **это только любовь**.* При распространении второй части предложения пауза становится факультативной.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137019/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---------).

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае ставится и запятая и тире. Вот [правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144) из справочника Розенталя.

В других случаях **тире** ставится после запятой, закрывающей придаточную часть, для усиления пунктуации, при «переломе» конструкции, перед словом ***это*** и т. д.: *Однажды я спросил себя: а что, если он вернётся, неожиданно явится к тебе, — ты будешь рад?;* ***Самое лучшее, что он мог сделать, — вовремя уйти**; Что это был за случай, в котором было столько неясного, — **этого**  он припомнить не мог; **Единственное, что мне здесь нравится, — это старый тенистый парк; Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, — что ж, ошибаться свойственно человеку***; *Он замолчал, но не потому, что ему не хватало слов, — ему не хватало дыхания; В смущении он говорил не то, что думал, — он произносил первые пришедшие на ум слова.*